# How can i send sms to my database entries

Tags: php, mysql, sms-gateway

i am able to send sms via php but in that i have to mention mobile number everytime i want that with the same script i can send sms to the entries stored in my database . 
here is my code:

```
<?php

//Your authentication key`enter code here`
$authKey = "API key";

//Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma
$mobileNumber = "+919425386214";

//Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.
$senderId = "Social";

//Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.
$message = urlencode("Test message");

//Define route 
$route = "04";
//Prepare you post parameters
$postData = array(
    'authkey' => $authKey,
    'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
    'message' => $message,
    'sender' => $senderId,
    'route' => $route
);
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//API URL
$url="https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php";

// init the resource
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
    //,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));


//Ignore SSL certificate verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


//get response
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//Print error if any
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
}
?>
```

please help so that i can send sms to my clients whom contact no. are stored in my database

Comment: i think you want dynamic data in this variable `$mobileNumber` ? means comma separated numbers in this variable?

Comment: yes i want same but the value to this variable will be numbers stored in my database

Comment: ishan Thanks for marking , i hope your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some query code to do it , for your help a sample code:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$mobileNumber = '';
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database name') or die (mysqli_error()); // give connection credentials here

if($conn){
$query = "Select mobile_number From User"; // change table name and column name accordingly.

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $mobileNumber .= $row['mobile_number'].',';
   }
}

}
$mobileNumber = substr($mobileNumber,0,strlen($mobileNumber)-1); // now you have all mobile numbers in , seperated form in this variable
```

**Note:- You can add this code in your current php code and do changes accordingly and you will get the output what you want.**

Comment: How to limit mobile numbers to 100 and then loop if having 10,000 mobile numbers in the database? Using @Anant code all numbers are selected.